# Find formula structure for a complex function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am looking to find the function formula structure of a repeating function like the one in the image linked below....

Something that repeats indefinitely (like a sine wave) on the X-axis.  Anybody can help me.

http://i57.tinypic.com/29nbb15.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the last answer didn't work for it was symmetrical

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}g(x)^2 & \text{ if } g(x)>0\\
                     \frac{g(x)^2}{9}& \text{ if } g(x) \leq 0\end{cases}$$ where $g(x) =2( x-[x])-1,5$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%282%28x%E2%88%92floor%5Bx%5D%29%E2%88%921%29%5E2

Comment: thank you... and what variable do I change to modify the point X where my Y = 0 ?   Example:  If I want my X1 to be 21 and my X2 to be 30?

Comment: you just need to scale take $\tilde{g}(x)= g\bigg(\frac{x}{30}\bigg) +1,5$ the period is now $30$ now $x_2=30$ to obtain $x_1=1$ just take $\hat{g}(x) =\tilde{g}(x)-1 + 1/30 $. To understand what is happenig you need to make some drawings. Finally scale each side $f(x)$  to make it continuous